# How to make StateListDrawable change background when button is pressed? (in xml)

Tags: android, android-layout

I am doing [Google's android tutorial on Drawables](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-drawables-styles-and-themes/index.html?index=..%2F..android-training#7).
I completed it but am stuck on this 'challenge' task:

> create a Drawable resource that changes the background of the
>   ImageButton to the same color as the border when the state of the
>   ImageButton is "pressed". You should also set the color of the text
>   inside the ImageButton elements to a selector that makes it white when
>   the button is "pressed".

To the [styles.xml see here for completed tutorial code before 'challenge'](https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-fundamentals-apps-v2/blob/master/Scorekeeper/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml), I modified ScoreButtons to access a new drawable, button_state

```
<style name="ScoreButtons" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_state</item>
    <item name="android:tint">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

drawable/button_state following the android docs https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_background_pressed"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        />

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_background_released"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        />
</selector>
```

button_background_pressed.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
</shape>
```

button_background_released.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
</shape>
```

There is no change when I press the buttons. What am I missing?

Comment: could you share your logic implementation? (inits listeners etc)?

Comment: the logic is the same as the completed tutorial here https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-fundamentals-apps-v2/tree/master/Scorekeeper I did not modify the logic because the changes are in XML. see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button_background_pressed should look like this, if I understood correctly

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="oval">

    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
</shape>
```

If your minimum version is android 21, then you can use the Ripple Drawable
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable

Comment: both answers work. so my child and I did a coin-toss to pick one.

Answer (score 1):

In your pressed drawable, you need to use the solid element to fill the shape with the desired color:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval"> 
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
</shape>
```

Check all available xml elements that you can include in a Shape element  [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#Shape).

Comment: both answers work. so my child and I did a coin-toss to pick one.